# Why can't I install Xcode7 beta5?

Tags: xcode7, dmg

I have downloaded Xcode7 beta5 from [Xcode link](https://developer.apple.com/xcode/downloads/).However,when I click the dmg file,and the prompt interface is:
[image]

Why there is a forbidden mark above the Xcode icon?Does anyone knows how to fix it.

My system version is OS X Yosemite **10.10.3**.

Comment: What version of OS X are you using?

Comment: OS X Yosemite 10.10.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. Xcode7 beta5 requires OSX version to be 10.10.4 or above.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it only installs OS X 10.10.3 or later.  Is that what you are running?